# error MSB4057: The target "pack" does not exist in the project when I create nuget package with MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, nuget

When I create a nuget package based on [this document](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/guides/create-net-standard-packages-vs2017) with Visual Studio 2017. I can create the nuget package from the Visual Studio, but I failed when I create the nuget with MSBuild command line:

```
msbuild /t:pack
```

The error info:

> MSB4057: The target "pack" does not exist in the project.

I have search [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48620913/error-msb4057-the-target-pack-does-not-exist-in-the-project-visual-studio-f) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49253244/teamcity-error-msb4057-the-target-pack-does-not-exist-in-the-project), but none of them resolve my issue.

So I do not know how to fix this issue, Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of project is this? 
Which version of VS are you using? 

The Pack SDK comes bundled with the .NET Core SDKs. 
Later versions of VS have this installed by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> error MSB4057: The target “pack” does not exist in the project when I create nuget package with MSBuild

It seems you are using the `.sln` solution path instead of the `.csproj` project path when you packing your package with MSBuild.

Since the package metadata is contained directly in the `.csproj` file, so you should switch the .sln solution path to the appropriate .csproj project path.

The command looks like:

```
msbuild "YourProjectPath\xxxx.csproj" /t:pack /p:Configuration=Release
```

Hope this helps.